# How Can I get an entry in the formatting bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose to have a formatting bar that composed by `Bold,List,Italic` etc. I need to add an entry in this formatting bar. Suppose to have an HTML page with a button:

```
<button component="category/post" id="new_topic" class="btn btn-primary">New Topic</button>
```

When I click on the button the program show me other new HTML code, where I can insert my text for topic. In this moment I need to load the entry. The formatting bar of new HTML created is:

```
<ul class="formatting-group">
     <li tabindex="-1" data-format="bold" title="Bold"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" data-format="italic" title="Italic"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" data-format="list" title="List"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" data-format="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="fa fa-strikethrough"></i></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" data-format="link" title="Link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" data-format="picture-o" title="Picture"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" data-format="zen" title="Zen Mode"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" data-format="emoji-extended" title="Emoji"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></li>
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <li class="img-upload-btn" data-format="picture" tabindex="-1" title="Upload Image"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i></li>
    <li class="file-upload-btn hide" data-format="upload" tabindex="-1" title="Upload File"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></li>
    </ul>
```

So my jquery code to add the entry is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '#new_topic', function() {
console.log("SONO DENTRO");
$('ul[class="formatting-group"]').append('<li tabindex="-1" data-format="schedula" title="Schedula Topic"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>');
                    });
                });
```

But when the new HTML page is loaded is not work. But if the HTML is just loaded work. I think there is a loaded problem. Anyone can help me?

Comment: This code actually works fine! [Check the code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAdxjg)

Comment: yes but when I click on button new topic the program create me formatting bar and I don'w see the new entry in the formatting bar. So I click again and as the new HTML is just loaded I can see the entry!

Comment: could you create a code pen with what you have? i can't recreate the issue you are experiencing!